# What is the difference between using こと and かた in a sentence with できます and わかります?

Tags: grammar

e.g. はなすこと and はなしかた
I am trying to learn about this grammar point for a test 
[image]

My notes for できます and わかります [image]

Answer (score 4):

(1) こと nominalizes a verb, so はなすこと is "speaking". 
(~が)できます means "can (do)~", so you can say:

> はなすことができます。I can do + speaking → I can speak.
>   [日本語]{にほんご}をはなすことができます。I can do + speaking Japanese → I can speak Japanese.

Likewise,

> かんじをよむことができます。I can read kanji.
>   すしをつくることができます。I can make sushi.

---

(2) かた is "way of ~"/"how to", so はなしかた is "way of speaking"/"how to speak".
(~が)わかります means "I know~"/"I understand~", so you can say:

> はなしかたがわかります。I know + the way of speaking. → I know how to speak.
>   [日本語]{にほんご}のはなしかたがわかります。I know + the way of speaking + of Japanese → I know how to speak Japanese.

Likewise,

> かんじのよみかたがわかります。I know how to read kanji.
>   すしのつくりかたがわかります。I know how to make sushi.